# Reverse inheritance

Tags: scala, inheritance, types

For a custom DSL, I have a set of data producers and consumers.  (It's actually a little more complicated than that, but this will suffice to set up the problem.)  Users set up a consumer, which may require a certain type of data.  I would like to make sure that the type system enforces that the correct type of data is sent to the correct consumer.

The possible elaborations of data are bounded inasmuch as it is possible to write a single data producer that can at least fill in sensible default values.  Thus, there should be a lower bound to all data types that consists of a supplier of default data.  Also, all data shares certain characteristics, so there should be an upper bound.  And data can be manipulated in ways that preserve the suitability for a given consumer, or which widen the suitability to more consumers.  Thus, the types should look something like

```
AllData <: D <: AnyData
```

What is an (or the most) compact and elegant way to encode this constraint in Scala, assuming that I do not actually want to require `AllData` to extend every other data type `D`?

Right now I just have a superclass that looks something like

```
class AnyData {
  def foo: Int => String = defaultIntToStringImpl
  def mapFoo(oo: String => String) = AllData((foo _) andThen oo)
}
```

and subclasses can override it

```
class LiteralNumberData extends AnyData {
  override val foo = (i: Int) => i.toString
}
```

and there is a case class that allows every method to be pluggable

```
case class AllData(override val foo: Int => String) {}
```

But then the consumers really only get to choose between `AnyData` and `AllData` if they're going to allow mappings, because the mappings all end up as `AllData`.  This doesn't provide as much safety for consumers as I'd like, and it's up to me to make sure I remember not to do anything in e.g. `LiteralNumberData` that cannot be packed into an `AllData`.

Answer (score 2):

I would make a constraint on the types as follows:

```
 trait ProdConsConstraint[Producer,Consumer]{
   type Output <: AnyData
 }
```

if I'm following you correctly. Then you could use dependent types to enforce the suitability of the types you're working with.

```
 def foo(prod: Producer, con: Consumer)(implicit ev:ProdConsConstraint[Producer,Consuer]): ev.Output = ???
```

This removes the need for a lower bound while also allowing you leeway to "open" things up via scoping of implicit parameters.

Hmm... this sounds overly complex. Maybe I'm not understanding the question enough.

Comment: No, not overly complex; if anything it doesn't capture the full problem.  But partial solutions are valuable!  I can do some checking manually, as long as it's not too much.